# Como faço para editar um JSON dentro do meu banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho um JSON salvo em meu banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como faço para editar esse json usando o PHP e salvando novamente ele no banco de dados.

O json que gostaria de alterar o valor é esse

```
{"3":{"tipo":"Premium","valor":"100","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"},"1":{"tipo":"Arena","valor":"50","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"}}
```

Gostaria de Alterar os valores **Vendas** para 10 e **Status** para

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `array_map` para percorrer o array criado com o `json_decode` e aplicar a alteração aonde você quiser:

```
    $string = '{"3":{"tipo":"Premium","valor":"100","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"},"1":{"tipo":"Arena","valor":"50","quantidade":"200","vendas":"0","status":"1"}}';

    // transforma em array
    $jsonArray = json_decode($string, true);

    $jsonArray = array_map(function($e){
         $e['vendas'] = 10; // altera a venda para 10
         $e['status'] = 2; // altera o status para 2
         return $e;
    }, $jsonArray);

    // transforma em json novamente
    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

**[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/a2WbH1)**

Uma outra opção é usar o `array_walk`:

```
    array_walk($jsonArray, function(&$e, $k){
         $e['vendas'] = 10; // altera a venda para 10
         $e['status'] = 2; // altera o status para 2
    });
```

Se você for alterar os valores manualmente:

```
    $jsonArray = json_decode($string, true); // transforma em array
    $jsonArray[3]['vendas'] = 20; // altera determinado valor
    echo json_encode($jsonArray); // transforma em json
```

Comment: e se eu quiser editar so umas das partes? por exemplo só a do tipo Premium.

Comment: @Joãopedro fiz a edição

Comment: Outra duvida, como faço para pegar o aquele valor "3" do json??

Comment: @Joãopedro como assim?

Comment: Fiz uma edição pra ajudar.

Comment: @Joãopedro coloquei no final da resposta o código. Mas amigo... Quando for assim, crie uma nova pergunta. =) Pois logo, logo, você vai descaracteriza-la.

Comment: Eu queria pegar os valores da array [PREMIUM] (valor, quantidade...) e substituir dentro do json tipo:"Premium" os valores (valor, quantidade...)

Comment: @Joãopedro  Agora que eu entendi mais ou menos o que você quer ...é melhor você criar uma nova pergunta e detalhar la...

Comment: Pronto, criei uma nova pergunta pra ficar mais organizado as coisas.

Comment: @Joãopedro se você puder, depois coloque a pergunta anterior... Ela pode ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90972/discussion-between-joao-pedro-and-andrei-coelho).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer direto pelo SQL através das funções para o tipo [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html):

```
UPDATE
    myTable
SET
    myColumn = JSON_SET(
        myColumn,
        '$.3.vendas', 10,
        '$.1.vendas', 10,
        '$.3.status', 0,
        '$.1.status', 0
    );
```

Lembrando que o tipo JSON e suas funções estão disponíveis apenas a partir da versão 5.7.8.

Comment: Quando você diz "*tipo*" quer dizer que podemos criar uma coluna do tipo `json`?!

Comment: O "tipo" é o tipo do dado da coluna, em vez de usar VARCHAR, use JSON

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam é verdade! Acabei de fazer um teste no banco! Não sabia disso! Achei que só na nova versão em NoSql que existia isso!

Comment: @LipESprY o tipo é JSON! =)

Comment: Vou começar a usar esse suporte! Valeu mano!

Comment: @AndreiCoelho suspeitei desde o princípio! (Burrice nossa! Tem a disgrama do link na resposta ¬¬)